# How to Detect Keypress in Applescript

Tags: applescript

I have several nested loops in an Applescript, but I need a simple way for the user to stop executing the entire script. A (rather inefficient) idea I had was to check if keys were pressed within the quickest loop, and pass error number -128 in a keypress event, but I can't find a way to detect what keys were pressed.
I've seen recommendations for Jon's Commands, but I can't seem to install it properly even though it's in my ApplicationScripts -- (keys pressed) doesn't work.
Alternately, is there a better way to stop running the script across multiple loops?

Comment: How is the user running your script?

Answer (score 1):

Try using command . to stop the script